# Sorting a matrix by the first column Julia

Tags: sorting, matrix, julia

I have a matrix like this in Julia:

```
5×2 Array{Float64,2}:
5.52777     7.51186e15
0.00444418  0.0311171 
3.26441     9.72657   
3.38447     1.7144e16 
0.459852    6.90901
```

I would like to order it by the first column and obtain something like this:

```
0.00444418  0.0311171 
0.459852    6.90901   
3.26441     9.72657   
3.38447     1.7144e16 
5.52777     7.51186e15
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Just for clarity sake, in your example, the array is already sorted by the first column correct?

Comment: There was an error copying the result I expected, corrected.

Comment: No worries! I’m glad you got an answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expected result you posted doesn't show that you want to order it by the first column, so it's not clear what you want.

If you want to sort the matrix by its first column you can use sortperm and indexing:

```
julia> m[sortperm(m[:,1]),:]
5×2 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.00444418  0.0311171 
 0.459852    6.90901   
 3.26441     9.72657   
 3.38447     1.7144e16 
 5.52777     7.51186e15
```

`sortperm(m[:,1])` returns the sorted indices of the first column which you then use to index the matrix.

A probably faster alternative would be to use `sortslices(m,dims=1)`, but this gets a little bit more difficult to call if e.g. you want to sort by the second column...

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. There was an error in my question and it was not clear, but corrected.